# Way to preventing users to checkin files to SVN

Tags: eclipse, svn

We have a java project maintained in a SVN repository. The developers are allowed to check in the code using eclipse. There is no restriction. I want to ensure only the reviewed code is allowed to check in to SVN by the developers. Is there a way or tool to do this, like some tool which generates a unique random id on completion of code review by the reviewer, on entering that id by the developer, the SVN should allow the developer to check in.

Comment: How is the workflow here? Does the code review take place at each developers individual computer, _before_ they check in their code to version control? Maybe it would be better to have the devs check in in a dev branch, and code review to review that branch and then check in into another branch.

Comment: We have one branch only in SVN. I am looking for an open source tool which can be integrated with eclipse SVN, which should allow the user to check in the code only after it is reviewed.